# I have a "missing expression" error and i can t find out why. there s the code down there

Tags: sql, count, expression

I need to select the first 3 `employees` with **maximum salary** and I get the error `at line 4 column 14`, right after the `count()` function. Can someone enlighten me?

```
select last_name
from employees
group by salary
having count(select max(salary) from employees group by salary)=3
order by salary desc;
```

Comment: what you had done so far please highlight your code?

Answer (score 2):

You would seem to want something like this:

```
select e.*
from employees e
order by e.salary desc
fetch first 3 rows only;
```

This selects the three employees with the highest salaries.  Not all databases support the ANSI standard `FETCH FIRST` clause.  You may need to use `LIMIT 3`, `SELECT TOP 3`, or something else.